# Rabanan cancelled out his mitzvah -- does it matter if his problem was active or passive?

Tags: shabbat, shema, derabanan, shofar, lomdus

There's the well-worn discussion of cases where someone did a mitzvah when the rabbis said not to, e.g. blowing shofar or taking lulav when the otherwise-right day was shabbos.

This is usually linked to the discussion of if someone said Shema after "midnight"; do they not get the "proper mitzvah" credit, or did the rabbis cancel out the mitzvah altogether.

While both of these involve the principle of rabbinic power to cancel a mitzvah obligation in a passive manner (*shev ve'al taaseh*), there's a pretty serious distinction: the shofar/lulav fellow is committing an act of *commission*, being active when the rabbis said to just sit there and do nothing. The fellow who spaced out and missed Shema for six hours sinned by omission -- they did nothing.

It would seem like a reasonable policy (and yes, it's baalabatish) to suggest that if you get up and cross a line the rabbis said not to, they will cancel out your mitzvah. But if you just did nothing, it's hard to say the rabbis then order you to keep doing more nothing!

Does anyone suggest such a sevara, and differentiate between the cases?

Comment: I wonder if the active violation could be considered a מצוה הבאה בעבירה.

Comment: It sounds more like the person would be a *zaken mamreh*?

Comment: The Halacha follows Rabbah Gamliel, who says that bdieved you are yotzei after chatzos

Comment: My brother just told me about the local Reform Temple, where they actually had services both days of RH/YK/Shmini Atzeres, but _only_ did shofar/lulav/Simchas Torah on the first day Shabbat - because that's when almost everyone comes!

Comment: Interesting question. How do you know that the Rabbanon _can_ "cancel out a mitzvah"? They can tell you not to do it, שב ואל תעשה, and you are supposed to listen to them, but does that mean that the mitzvah isn't there at all?

Comment: @MichoelR that's a machlokes rishonim, how to interpret various places the Gemara says "you didn't get the mitzvah." (It may simply mean "in the right way", or "with full credit.") On your other point: there's actually a Reform responsum allowing shofar on shabbos for places that keep only one day, based on the Taz's klal. It's a nice try, but incorrect -- the Taz meant the rabbis don't (or can't, depending on how you learn) negate *ever* doing a mitzvah, not that they have to let you do it every single year.

Comment: @Shalom Thank you. Do you have sources for that, it sounds very fundamental? I mean the rishonim.

Comment: @MichoelR https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.634.4?lang=bi&with=Biur%20Halacha&lang2=en   לדעת התוספות בסוכה ד"ג מן התורה לא יצא כיון דרבנן גזרו ע"ז ואמרו כאלו לא קיים מצות סוכה ולהר"ן וריטב"א רק מדרבנן